# Find Solution regarding 2-Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, operations-research

I try to understand that, but I have no clue what do to and how to do it.

$A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with $rg(A)=m$.
Find the solution for $Ax = b$, which is regarding to the $2$-norm (I guess that's the Euclidean norm) the shortest.

---

**Problem:**

$\min (1/2)x^T*x$
s.t.: $Ax=b$

**Hint:** Put with the variable $y$ and maximize over $y$ the constraint into the objective function and use the Minimax Lemma.

Comment: what is $rg(A)$ mean...range? How do you know that $Ax=b$ is consistent, since $A$ is not invertible?